# How to select grub entry via PS2 port?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, serial-port, ps2

We want to output the grub entry to serial port and select the grub entry on another machine via serial port.

We have two machines.

For the machine with built-in serial port, we followed the instruction at [1] and successfully configured the grub and can select the grub entry from a remote machine via serial port.

For the machine that has no built-in serial port on the mother board. We added a PCI card [2] which provides two serial ports. However, the add-on PCI card is an external device and will not be recognized until the Linux kernel is loaded. So we cannot see the grub entry from a remote machine via serial port. The machine does have a PS2 port. We are thinking if it is possible to output the grub entry to the PS2 port and select the grub entry from a remote machine via the PS2 port?

Does anyone experience the similar situation before? or 
Does anyone have any suggestion on another way to select the grub entry from a remote machine? 
We really appreciate it if you could provide any pointer to the possible solutions.

Thanks in advance!

[1] https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Working_with_the_serial_console

[2] [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-RS232-Serial-Adapter-PCI2S550/dp/B00006B8C0/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1446675692&sr=8-3&keywords=serial+port+pci](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006B8C0)

Answer (score 1):

Double check your motherboard and motherboard manual, your motherboard might have headers on the board instead of a physical serial port.  You'd have to get something like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200515&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Hard%20Drive%20Adapters-_-N82E16812200515&gclid=CjwKEAiA9uaxBRDYr4_hrtC3tW8SJAD6UU8GBP2N6T_oqR_HqDfRHml0l980027X164tyvdBVdL8cxoCNETw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) to allow attachment of a cable to it.

If your board really doesn't have a serial port, you will have to invest in a "Remote Management" card of some type, which will redirect BIOS/UEFI-level KVM in hardware to serial or Ethernet.  An example of one is [here](https://www.arktel.com/catalog/p-80-megarac-g4-remote-management-pci.aspx).